# Customize recovery partition

Tags: high-sierra, recovery

I often run into situations where it's more convenient to boot up in recovery partition than a system partition. However, many important features are missing in the recovery partition. I know that you can add applications to it (Disk Drill does this), but it seems like a lot of important but not essential framework is not included, and if I copy all of them to the recovery partition I can't boot up. (Note: I'm referring to a restore/image of the recovery partition dmg onto another separate read-write volume when I write "recovery partition".)

An important feature of recovery partition is that I can set csrutil status, which is impossible in any configuration of the system partition. There is also no security features enabled, which is helpful in times.

Is there a way to customize the recovery system and still get it to boot/work? I want to have a working Finder (if there is low disk space/I want to remove some extensions/filesystems, etc.), better graphics (stop flashing everytime the display changes), and access to all my command-line tools (I guess I can just copy /usr over, but many of them still relies on frameworks that are not present).

Comment: If your **Mac** has **USB 3** capability then why don't you just install **macOS** to a **USB 3** flash drive and boot from it. Then you have a fully functioning **macOS** to work with from a regular **GUI** environment!

Comment: The only real reason is I'm unable to change `csrutil` status on a normal system, and a normal system loads too much stuff and is extremely slow (I've tested it before).

Comment: The Recovery environment is meant to be the smallest environment possible to *recover* your Mac from a failure, not to be an alternate macOS desktop environment.  Smallest because you don't want it to take up valuable space and/or want to download only what's necessary over the internet for efficiency.  If "low disk space" is an issue - you need to add more storage space - it's super cheap at this point.

Comment: If you want to change the status of SIP without using `csrutil` then use rEFInd. When I want to disable SIP, I restart to the Mac Startup Manager, select rEFInd, disable SIP, then boot to macOS.